# Change resolution without being able to see desktop

Tags: windows, display, windows-10, remote, display-settings

I am traveling.  I use Splashtop to connect to my home PC.  I changed the resolution and now my screen looks like an old NES game with a dusty cartridge or a scrambled cable channel.  I can run commands.  I can also log out and see the login screen properly.  As soon as I log in it goes back to the scrambled image.

I'm running Windows 10.  Is there *anything* I can do to change my resolution without being able to see?  command line?  I could reboot into safe mode but I'm afraid my splashtop streamer would not launch.

Ideas?

Comment: Possible [so] duplicate: [Batch command to change the resolution of a computer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15324290) and [How to change screen resolution and the size of items using command line/programmaticly/batch or macro?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32153038)

Comment: That question has much more specific requirements and my question has a much more specific scenario.  I don't believe they are duplicates.

Comment: Can you use powershell? `Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768 -Force` ([Set-DisplayResolution](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/JJ603036%28v=WPS.630%29.aspx))

Comment: According to an SO question that is only available in Server Core (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817636/why-is-my-set-displayresolution-command-in-powershell-missing)

Comment: Looks like you are out of luck then :/

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't technically answer my question, I did find a solution for anyone that has this issue and uses splashtop.

In splashtop, I edited the connection to the PC in question and I changed the resolution to 800x600.  When I connected it forced that resolution and everything looked fine (relatively speaking).  I was then able to change it back to "best fit on local device" and it still looked good.

I won't accept this as I would still like to find a way to do this blind regardless of what remote software you are using.